# C - declare pthread_barrier - syntax error, data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: c, pthreads

Here is my code

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define C_NORMAL    "\033[0m"
#define C_OWNER "\033[1;35m"
#define C_CASHIER   "\033[0;33m"
#define C_CASHIER_TAB   "\033[0;36m"
#define C_CUSTOMER  "\033[0;32m"
#define C_CUSTOMER_ERR  "\033[1;31m"

#define MAX_TICKETS 50
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS   60

int tickets = 10;               // the number of available tickets
int customers = 13;             // the number of customers
int error = 0;                  // keeps track of whether error occured in releasing resources

volatile int reservations[MAX_TICKETS]; // owner of each ticket, 0 = no owner
volatile int reservation_attempts = 0;  // number of finished reservation attempts

//All control structs for synchronization and critical section solving
pthread_barrier_t barrier_tickets_reserved;     // barrier for synchronization - waits for all tickets to be reserved
pthread_barrier_t barrier_tickets_payed;    // barrier for synchronization - waits for all tockets to be payed for
pthread_barrier_t barrier_start;        // barrier for synchronization - initial synchronization of all threads
pthread_barrier_t barrier_money_transfer;   // barrier for synchronization - waits for the money to be send to the owner
pthread_barrier_t barrier_receipt_transfer; // barrier for synchronization - waits for receipt to be recieved by cashier
pthread_mutex_t mutex_reservations;     // mutex for solving critical section of accesing reservations 
pthread_mutex_t mutex_atempts;      // mutex for solving critical section of accesing reservation attempts
```

and here is my error:

```
tickets_solved.c:57: error: syntax error before ‘barrier_tickets_reserved’
tickets_solved.c:57: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘barrier_tickets_r
tickets_solved.c:57: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

Same errors goes for all other pthread barriers but not for pthread mutexes.
It would seem like the code does not recognize pthread barrier as working type, but I don't know why it would be so.

And my makefile looks like so:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall -D_REENTRANT

LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS = -lpthread -lrt

RM = /bin/rm -f

OBJECTS = *.o
BACKUPS = *~ *.bak
PROGRAM = tickets_solved

all: $(PROGRAM)

ticket_solved: $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    @echo Deleting objects, backups and programs
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(BACKUPS) $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code? Which platform, which compiler, and which flags?

Comment: gcc -Wall -D_REENTRANT    tickets_solved.c  -lpthread -lrt -o tickets_solved
This is line from when makefile compeles the code. Would anything else help? (where tickets_colved.c is this file). And I compile it on linux.

Comment: Sounds like your pthreads implementation doesn't include barriers. I think they were optional until POSIX 2017.

Comment: I am not sure i follow. With #include <pthread.h> i should have barriers at hand do i not?

Comment: All standard functions/variables related to thread barriers start with `pthread_barrier*`. So, `barrier_tickets_reserved` is something of yours [and you do _not_ show it]. However, `pthread_barrier_t` is an extension, gated by `__USE_XOPEN2K`. You can _not_ define this directly. This is defined when `_POSIX_SOURCE` is defined. So, above any and _all_ `#include` add `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` to ensure things get defined correctly. Note that `#define _GNU_SOURCE` will turn on _everything_. To see the gory details, look at `/usr/include/features.h`

Comment: @CraigEstey New code should use `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, not `_POSIX_SOURCE`.

Comment: Barriers are a part of POSIX 2008 and later, but they were optional in POSIX 2004 and were not a part of POSIX 1997.  Either you aren't requesting a sufficiently modern version of POSIX (I'd recommend `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` before including any system headers, but there are other ways to achieve essentially the same effect, such as setting `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to inscrutable values such as `200809L`) or your platform doesn't support barriers.

Comment: @Oka Yes, I misread the hierarchy. `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` needs a special value that is the level of compliance (e.g.) `200809L`. So, `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`. But, that seems a bit complex to use/remember. I just use `#define _GNU_SOURCE` because it obviates the need for all the [needless, IMO] complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` at the beginning of the file (above all other `#include`) fixed the issue.